# Unzip the archive with more than one entry

Tags: linux, curl, zip, pipe, archive

I'm trying to decompress ~8GB `.zip` file piped from `curl` command. Everything I have tried is being interrupted at <1GB and returns a message:

> ... has more than one entry--rest ignored

I've tried: `funzip`, `gunzip`, `gzip -d`, `zcat`, ... also with different arguments - all end up in the above message.

The datafile is public, so it's easy to repro the issue:

```
curl -L https://archive.org/download/nycTaxiTripData2013/faredata2013.zip | funzip > datafile
```

Comment: Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or superuser instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the mentioned file deflates to a single file? If it extracts to multiple files you unfortunately cannot unzip on the fly.

Zip is a container as well as compression format and it doesn't know where the new file begins. You'll have to download the whole file and unzip it.

Comment: yes, it's multi-part archive, as question title suggests.. So there is no way at all to decompress multi-part archive from `stdout`?